# Switching an infinite sum and finite integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation

Under what conditions is it true that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\int_a^b\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_a^b f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are finite and $f_n(x)$ is any function (real or complex)? I know that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is absolutely convergent then (1) is true. But, under what other conditions is (1) true?

Comment: Conditions stronger than the equation. If you have a concrete problem, better post it instead. Depending on the concrete functions, a use of other limit properties of the integral (monotone, dominated convergence) could produce the result. Perhaps a summation/integration by parts can turn the problem into a case in which Fubini applies.

Answer (score 1):

Well to give you a proper answer, I will start from the trivial case.

You can interchange them if they are both in indefinite forms.

$$\int\sum x\ \Delta x\ \text{d}x = \int \frac{x(x-1)}{2} + c\ \text{d}x$$

$$\sum\int x\ \text{d}x\ \Delta x = \sum \frac{x^2}{2} + c\ \Delta x$$

both equal to $\frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^2}{4} + C_1x + C_2$

The reason why this holds true is because their representations in differential operators commute, say

What can one do instead, if we have an infinite series for example? Well the point is to look at this:

$$\int_{\Omega}\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_{\Omega} \lim_{k\to+\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^k f_n(x)\ \text{d}x$$

and if you can justify exchanging the integral with this limit, then it shall immediately follow that

$$\lim_{k\to+\infty}\int_{\Omega}  \sum_{n = 0}^k f_n(x)\ \text{d}x = \lim_{k\to+\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^k \int_{\Omega} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x$$

Understanding when a sum can be exchanged with an integral is reducible to understanding when a limit can be exchanged with an integral.

There are a variety of classical results from measure theory that allow you to do just that. The two most widely used are the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

To say, the monotone convergence theorem tells you that if $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ $\forall n$ and $\forall x$, then you have

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_{\Omega} \lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x
$$

Translating into a sum language, you have that if $f_n(x) \geq 0$ $\forall n$ and $\forall x$:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_{\Omega} \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x$$

The dominated convergence theorem instead states that if $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all $x$ **and** there exist an integrable function $g(x)$ such that $|f(x)| \leq g(x)$, then

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x =\int_{\Omega} \lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x$$

And again, translating this into series it means that if $\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all $x$, **and** there is some integrable function $g(x)$ such that $$\bigg|\sum_{n = 0}^k f_n(x)\bigg| \leq g(x)$$ for every $k$, then

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_{\Omega} \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} f_n(x)\ \text{d}x$$

Eventually, the most common approach to utilize this observation is to note that

\begin{align}
\bigg|\sum_{n = 0}^k f_n(x)\bigg| & \leq \sum_{n = 0}^k f_n(x)
\\\\ & \leq \sum_{n = 0}^k |f_n(x)|
\end{align}

That is: if the sum converges absolutely (to an integrable function), then the integral and the summation can be exchanged.